# How to mock methods in dynamically loaded jars

Tags: java, class, reflection, mockito

I have a class called Price with constructor, which I am dynamically loading via reflection:

```
public Price(Context context, String pair) {
    this.context = context;
    this.value1 = pair.substring(0, 3);
    this.value2 = pair.substring(3, 6);
    this.dps = context.getService().getm1(value1, value2).getm2();
}
```

However I want to mock the Context object

and I want

```
context.getService().getm1(value1, value2).getm2()
```

to return 5.

Here is what I have tried

```
//mocking the Context class
Class<?> contextClass = urlClassLoader.loadClass("com.algo.Context");
constructor =contextClass.getConstructor();
Object context = Mockito.mock(contextClass);

//trying to instantiate the Price class
Class<?> priceClass = urlClassLoader.loadClass("com.algo.Price");
constructor = priceClass.getConstructor(contextClass,String.class);
Mockito.when(context.getService().getm1(value1, value2).getm2().thenReturn(5));
Object price = constructor.newInstance(context,"PRICES");
```

However I have a red line under

```
context.getService()
```

The error says

```
The method getService() is undefined for the type Object
```

How can I get around this, my end goal is to create the Price object with the variable

```
dps
```

being an int 5, that is why I want to mock the Context object.

Comment: Context is of type `Object` - just cast it. Btw: you're talking about a compiler error

Comment: it is a compile error, casting does not resolve it

Comment: why is your `context` variable of type `Object` and not `Context`

Comment: I am dynamically loading the Context class from a jar, I cant make it type Context, i get compile error

Comment: what does getService returns? I'm not sure you can mock directly context.getService().getm1(value1, value2).getm2(), you need to mock context.getService(), then service.getm1(value1, value2), then m1.getm2()

Comment: get Service returns an object of type Service

Answer (score 1):

For me the only way is to implement your whole test using reflection which is really laborious especially in your case as you will need to do the same thing for each method call as you cannot mock directly `context.getService().getm1(value1, value2).getm2()`.

**Assuming that I have a class `Context` as below**

```
public class Context {

    public int getm1(String value1, String value2) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

**A normal test case would be:**

```
@Test
public void normal() throws Exception {
    Context context = Mockito.mock(Context.class);
    Mockito.when(context.getm1(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(5);
    Assert.assertEquals(5, context.getm1("foo", "bar"));
}
```

**The same test using reflection would be:**

```
@Test
public void reflection() throws Exception {
    ... // Here I get the classloader
    // Get the class by reflection
    Class<?> contextClass = urlClassLoader.loadClass("com.algo.Context");
    // Mock the class
    Object context = Mockito.mock(contextClass);
    // Get the method by reflection
    Method method = contextClass.getMethod("getm1", String.class, String.class);
    // Invoke the method with Mockito.anyString() as parameter 
    // to get the corresponding methodCall object
    Object methodCall = method.invoke(context, Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString());
    // Mock the method call to get what we expect
    Mockito.when(methodCall).thenReturn(5);
    // Test the method with some random values by reflection
    Assert.assertEquals(5, method.invoke(context, "foo", "bar"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot really understand this issue. If you are working with an unknown type it cannot be typed as Context within the construtor.

But independently, an approach would be to create interfaces representing the expected structure of context and then mock the interfaces to return the value.
It is not necessary to really load the dynamic class within the test if it is mocked either way.